# Download HTTPS pages with HttpClient 4.5 via proxy in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https, proxy, httpclient

I try to download https pages with Apache HttpClient 4.5 via proxies.

Some download finishes successfully, but with others I get errors.

Why? Do I something wrong?

```
package hu.istvanbohm.mypublist.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.config.CookieSpecs;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class TestHttpClientDownloader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        String rawUrl = "https://*********.com";
        String[] proxies = {"1.161.158.86:8080","1.179.183.27:3128","1.179.201.18:3128","1.207.245.184:80",
                "1.207.62.194:3128","1.234.28.160:80","1.234.28.18:80",
                "1.234.28.20:80","1.234.28.36:80","1.234.28.42:80"};

        URI targetUri = new URI(rawUrl);

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(100);

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(cm)
                .setRetryHandler(new StandardHttpRequestRetryHandler(0,false))
                .setConnectionTimeToLive(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                .build();

        for(String proxyString : proxies) {
            String[] proxyParts = proxyString.split(":");
            String proxyUrl = proxyParts[0];
            int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt(proxyParts[1]);

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(targetUri);
            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(new HttpHost(proxyUrl,proxyPort))
                    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                    .setSocketTimeout(25000)
                    .setConnectTimeout(25000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(25000)
                    .build();
            request.setConfig(config);
            HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
            context.setAttribute("http.protocol.handle-redirects", false);  
            HttpEntity entity = null;
            try {
                System.out.println("Submit: Executing request " + request.getRequestLine() + 
                        " to " + request.getURI()  + " via " + request.getConfig().getProxy());
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request,context);
                try {
                    entity = response.getEntity(); 
                    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                    if(entity!=null && statusLine.getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        String result=EntityUtils.toString(entity,org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.getOrDefault(entity).getCharset());
                        if(result!=null && result.length()>0) System.out.println("Download OK!");
                    } else if(entity!=null){
                        System.out.println("Error - Http status is not OK: " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    }
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error - HttpClient response: " + ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    if(entity!=null) {
                        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                    }
                    if(response!=null) {
                        response.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error - HttpClient execute: " + ex.getMessage());
            }    
        }

        try {
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error - HttpClient close: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        cm.close();
    }
}
```

This is the output that the program generates:

```
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.161.158.86:8080
Error - HttpClient execute: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.179.183.27:3128
Download OK!
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.179.201.18:3128
Download OK!
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.207.245.184:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Connection reset
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.207.62.194:3128
Error - HttpClient execute: Connection reset
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.234.28.160:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.234.28.18:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.234.28.20:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.234.28.36:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Submit: Executing request GET https://**********.com HTTP/1.1 to https://**********.com via http://1.234.28.42:80
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Sample outputs with extended error info and sample url:

```
Submit: Executing request GET https://en.blog.wordpress.com/ HTTP/1.1 to https://en.blog.wordpress.com/ via http://1.234.28.42:80
2016/08/07 17:42:50:125 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /1.234.28.42:80
2016/08/07 17:42:50:537 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 192.168.0.9:53098<->1.234.28.42:80
2016/08/07 17:42:50:950 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Tunnel to target created.
2016/08/07 17:42:50:955 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2016/08/07 17:42:50:955 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2016/08/07 17:42:50:955 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2016/08/07 17:42:51:371 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-9: Shutdown connection
2016/08/07 17:42:51:371 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
2016/08/07 17:42:51:371 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 9][route: {tls}->http://1.234.28.42:80->https://en.blog.wordpress.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 100]
Error - HttpClient execute: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Submit: Executing request GET https://en.blog.wordpress.com/ HTTP/1.1 to https://en.blog.wordpress.com/ via http://1.207.245.184:80
2016/08/07 17:42:19:867 CEST [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
2016/08/07 17:42:19:867 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {tls}->http://1.207.245.184:80->https://en.blog.wordpress.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 100]
2016/08/07 17:42:19:868 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 3][route: {tls}->http://1.207.245.184:80->https://en.blog.wordpress.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 3 of 100]
2016/08/07 17:42:19:868 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {tls}->http://1.207.245.184:80->https://en.blog.wordpress.com:443
2016/08/07 17:42:19:869 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to /1.207.245.184:80
2016/08/07 17:42:20:353 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 192.168.0.9:53088<->1.207.245.184:80
2016/08/07 17:42:21:487 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Tunnel to target created.
2016/08/07 17:42:21:491 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2016/08/07 17:42:21:492 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2016/08/07 17:42:21:492 CEST [DEBUG] SSLConnectionSocketFactory - Starting handshake
2016/08/07 17:42:21:509 CEST [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-3: Shutdown connection
2016/08/07 17:42:21:509 CEST [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
2016/08/07 17:42:21:509 CEST [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 3][route: {tls}->http://1.207.245.184:80->https://en.blog.wordpress.com:443][total kept alive: 2; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 100]
Error - HttpClient execute: Connection reset
```

Comment: You will need to find more details as to why specific connections are failing.  Can you share which of these URL's are failing.  Can you try adding additional logging (e.g. https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) and see if you get a specific error ?

Comment: I updated my question with 2 example output with additional debug details and an example uri in it. i couldnt post all because of the length limitation. Because of this i removed the header informations too from the debug logs, if they are needed please ask for them again.